# Where can I ask for help regarding questions on the LSAT (Law school admission test)?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where can I ask questions when I need help with the Law School Admission Test ([LSAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_School_Admission_Test))? I am trying to practice LSAT questions and I'm having some problems with it.

---

Example question from the LSAT that I would be asking about:

> Most of the students who took Spanish 101 at the university last
> semester attended every class session. However, each student
> who received a grade lower than B minus missed at least one class
> session.
>
> Which one of the following statements about the students
> who took Spanish 101 at the university last semester can be
> properly inferred from the information above?
>
> A. [...]

Comment: Looking at what you dumped on Law.se I would say none of these questions are a good fit for any site in the Stack Exchange network. Try reddit or Quora, or one of the many university sites that offer FAQs and other guidance.

Comment: i thought stack exchange is to help with these kind of questions?

Comment: I don't think so. And certainly not by posting an image of the question and then with minimal effort expect us to complete your training. As I said earlier: reddit and Quora happily take that kind of one-on-one tutor kind of questions. On SE we are more looking for creating a body of knowledge. And that needs careful asked questions with answers that have long lasting value.

Comment: For context, [OP already posted this on Meta Law](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1500/26771) and was redirected here.

Answer (score 6):

That question is not about Law but about [reading comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reading_comprehension); asking others (family, friends, random people on the Internet like us) kind of defeats the purpose.

If you have trouble understanding the question because it's not in your native language, we can help you out at [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) but *please* [include your own thoughts so far](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/18673), otherwise we won't be able to provide an adequate answer.